# Using RegionFunction to constrain the surface shown by a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, regions

I'm working with an equation where the portion of the surface $z=x^2+2+\sin(3x-2y)$ lies above the region inside the circle $(x-2)^2+(y+4)^2=1$.

My code is:

```
Clear[x, y]

eq2 = x^2 + 2 + Sin[3*x - 2*y];
eq3 = (x - 2)^2 + (y + 4)^4 == 1;
ploteq2 = 
  Plot3D[x^2 + 2 + Sin[3x - 2y], {x, -4, 10}, {y, -5, -4},
    PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> 
    Purple, RegionFunction -> ((#1 - 2)^2 + (#2 + 4)^4 ≤ 1 &)]
```

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the output as my graph is being displayed, but it's only the range I'm having difficulty adjusting. No matter what I try for y range (or x range), it either shrinks or I get a blank plot. Also, when I look at the plot over the x and y ranges I have chosen, it doesn't look like the partial surface is inside the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method that is slightly less fiddly than using `RegionFunction` would be to construct an `ImplicitRegion[]`, and use that in `Plot3D[]`:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[(x - 2)^2 + (y + 4)^4 <= 1, {x, y}];
Plot3D[x^2 + 2 + Sin[3 x - 2 y], {x, y} ∈ reg]
```

[image: plot over a disk]

In fact, restricting to a disk can be done more compactly, if you know the center and the radius of a disk:

```
Plot3D[x^2 + 2 + Sin[3 x - 2 y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[{2, -4}, 1]]
```

This also happens to be much faster.

Comment: This was actually how it's supposed to look, as the it is suppose to be circular. I was fiddly with the range and couldn't get the correct shape, but you got it right.

Answer (score 2):

```
rp = RegionPlot3D[(x - 2)^2 + (y + 4)^2 <= 1, {x, -4, 10}, {y, -5, -4}, {z, -2, 100}, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5, LightBlue], BoundaryStyle -> None];
p3doutside = Plot3D[x^2 + 2 + Sin[3 x - 2 y], {x, -4, 10}, {y, -5, -4}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5, Orange], 
   RegionFunction -> ((#1 - 2)^2 + (#2 + 4)^2 >= 1 &)];
p3dinside = Plot3D[x^2 + 2 + Sin[3 x - 2 y], {x, -4, 10}, {y, -5, -4}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Purple, 
  RegionFunction -> ((#1 - 2)^2 + (#2 + 4)^2 <= 1 &)]

Show[rp, p3doutside, p3dinside  , 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 4}, {-5, -4}, {0, 30}}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

```
Show[p3dinside, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {-5, -4}, {0, 30}}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: please, correct your code related with the equation of the circle bounding the plot ;))

Comment: Thank you @Jose. Done.

Answer (score 0):

I think that basically, you have to play with the `BoxRatios` to scale the axis range proportionally. The problem here is the high ratio between them. I mean, one axis has a high range that minimises the length of the others, thus hindering the visualisation. Oh, there is also an error in your code relating the equation of the circle:

```
Plot3D[x^2 + 2 + Sin[3 x - 2 y], {x, 1, 3}, {y, -5, -4}, 
PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
RegionFunction -> ((#1 - 2)^2 + (#2 + 4)^2 <= 1 &), 
PlotStyle -> Cyan, ImageSize -> Medium, BoxRatios -> #] & /@ {{1, 1/2, 10}, {1, 1/2, 1}}
```

[image: plot]